# compare two csv file and write missing data on seperate csv

Tags: linux, shell, csv, awk

please help with me on awk scenerios

I have two csv and I need to compare two csv file and have to write missing column value along with the table name on separate csv file

File.csv

```
Table Name  Column Name
Class5  Tamil
Class5  English
Class5  Maths
Class5  Physics
Class5  Chemistry
Class6  Tamil
Class6  English
Class6  Maths
Class6  Chemistry
Class7  Tamil
Class7  English
Class7  Maths
Class7  Physics
Class7  Chemistry

File2.csv 

Table Name  Column Name
Class5  Tamil
Class5  English
Class5  Maths
Class5  Physics
Class5  Chemistry
Class6  Tamil
Class6  English
Class6  Maths
Class6  Physics
Class6  Chemistry
```

Expecting Output:

```
Missing Table(On file1)     Missing column(on file1)    Missing table(on file2)   Missing column(on file2)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class6                                Physics                   
                                                          class7                   Tamil
                                                          class7                   English
                                                          class7                   Maths
                                                          class7                   Physics
                                                          class7                   Chemistry
```

Comment: Neither of those look like CSV data... Where are the commas?

Comment: I just wrote scenerios. could you please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add your effort, what you have tried so far.

Comment: yes I planned to count table name by using groupby count, if count matches with file2 then their is no missing data... if that count doesn't match then have to write exact missing data along with filename on it...

Comment: Please post the exact data.

Comment: I have added screenshot for exact missing data  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCGLt.jpg please refer above my file and file2

Comment: @Raki, please do not post screen shots of samples, kindly add samples in your post with CODE TAGS only.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yes changed please remove [hold] im newbiee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Unix **comm** command.

Before passing your files to [comm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/comm.htm) command, you need to first sort them.

To get lines missing in File1.csv you have to do something like this,

```
comm -23 <(sort File2.csv | uniq) <(sort File1.csv | uniq)
```

To get lines missing in File2.csv you have to do something like this,

```
comm -23 <(sort File1.csv | uniq) <(sort File2.csv | uniq)
```

Comment: Hi im getting Error : -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @Raki try it again, there was a minor syntax error in his code

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks for edit :)